# Prove that number can be divided by 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, exponential-function, divisibility

I need to prove that for each 2 <= n ∈ N

$5^{3n-4} + 8*11^{n-2}$ divides by three

The question says I can use induction or any other way. I tried to use induction but couldn’t get any further after setting n = n + 1.

$5^{3(n+1) - 4}$ + $8*11^{n+1-2}$ = $5^{3n-1}$ + $8*11^{n-1}$ = ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your attempts in the question. You're much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: I have added more information my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base you made already.

Now, by assumption of the induction we obtain:
$$5^{3n-1}+8\cdot11^{n-1}=125\left(5^{3n-4}+8\cdot11^{n-2}\right)-1000\cdot11^{n-2}+88\cdot11^{n-2}=$$
$$=125\left(5^{3n-4}+8\cdot11^{n-2}\right)-912\cdot11^{n-2}$$ is divisible by $3$.

Thus, by the axioma of the induction $5^{3n-4}+8\cdot11^{n-2}$ is divisible by $3$ for any natural $n\geq2$.